# How To Remove A Random Object From Arraylist?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

So if this was my class:

my questions are, at condition 2 of the step() function, how do i remove that object from the arraylist? I am not sure because that object was chosen randomly by the Random function

```
import java.util.Random;

public class test{

private ArrayList<list> holder;


    public class(){

    int i = 0;

        holder = new ArrayList<Student>();

        for (i=0;i<S;i++){

            holder.add(new holder(i, library));
        }
}


public void step(){

box = students.get(random.nextInt(holder.size()));

if (condition 1){

do this

} else if (condition 2){

** remove the random object from arraylist (how?)**

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the java.util.Random that you imported to randomly generate a value to remove.

So you could do Radom rand = new Random();

`rand.nextInt(<MAX_TO_GENERATE>) + <MIN_TO_GENERATE>;`

MAX_TO_GENERATE is the value you want it to go up to (remember that Random is exclusive, so if you do 100 it will only go up to 99), and then set MIN_TO_GENERATE to the lowest value you'd like it to generate.

It appears that you're adding people to an ArrayList and this list could contain 5,000 people, so maybe have a variable that holds the count of Students. It seems like you were planning to do this with i, but I'm not completely sure.

EDIT:
Once you generate a value, assign it to a variable such as

`int randomNum = rand.nextInt(<MAX_TO_GENERATE>) + <MIN_TO_GENERATE>;`

and then you can do an If statement to remove it, such as:

`if(holder.get(randomNum) != null)
{
    holder.remove(randomNum);
}`

Answer (score 0):

Approach one, simply make your index a variable.

```
public void step(){
    int index=random.nextInt(holder.size());
    box = students.get(index);
    if (condition 1){
        //do this - this is a comment
    } 
    else if (condition 2){
        students.remove(index);
    }
}
```

Approach 2, if your class Object is not type int or Integer:

```
public void step(){
    box = students.get(random.nextInt(holder.size()));
    if (condition 1){
        //do this - this is a comment
    } 
    else if (condition 2){
        students.remove(box);
    }
}
```

Hopefully that should solve it. Also, JavaDocs are your friends, refer them to see which methods do what and how to invoke them.